# Intellij local history slow show, why?

Tags: intellij-idea

I've used Intellij since 2007. The last couple of versions, local history is slow.

When I mean slow, I am preferring to viewing the changes. It seems there is a new implementation being used, god knows why. Maybe using git and git history in the background, but it definitely was faster in the past.

Is there perhaps some setting that could be tuned?

Comment: What do you mean by slow? What action do you perform and how long does it take? Please share the [CPU snapshot](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241235) for this problem. Such issues should be better [reported to YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA). There is the special Performance Problem category.

Comment: I am tired of reporting things to youtrack and then wait 3 years. If you check the local history, you will see a list of changes the file was modified or for a directory a list of any change. When you move in between that list ... or click in the middle ... intellij loads to load the file and present the diff. This has become very slow. It did not use to be like this before.

Comment: Can't reproduce, please report to YouTrack with the CPU snapshot if you need it solved, it's unlikely than anyone else except JetBrains will be able to fix it, makes no sense to complain on SO.

Comment: I've reset cache several times, it is the same regardless. Maybe it has to do with me using symlinks for most of my workspace and is what takes the extra time, i don't see why though.

Comment: CPU snapshot should help to understand why.

Comment: How do I start one, and stop it, and send file to?

Comment: All the answers are in the document I've linked in the very first comment.

Comment: Before I make one, I will record a video and you tell me wether our environment differ.

Comment: What I think is slow might be perfectly fine for you, but I am comparing it to older behavior and defintely slower now. can barely use it anymore.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Here is the video: https://filebin.net/axhklq936r91hklb

Comment: One reason it might have become like this is that full changes are no longer stored but only diffs, so when I click on one, a computation has to be done backwards or similar to get me the changes at a certain point. It might save disk space, but costs in processing. For me, I don't care. I also have a I9 9900K with 64GB ram and an NVME disk. I would hate to wonder how it is behaving for laptops or slower computers.

Comment: I also spent half an hour looking through the Help menu (which is not sorted in any good way, alphabetic might be good) for Diagnostics but could not find anything, see here: https://imgur.com/a/7rIwdsR ... the CPU snapshot guide might need updating. The search in help menu is incredibly slow by way ... even just clicking on help is slow.

Comment: See the following screenshots which should help you to get it working, it looks like performance testing plug-in is disabled: https://i.imgur.com/laNB7CJ.png
https://i.imgur.com/MUw8Fex.png.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Did you see the video?

Comment: I did. Yes, it's slow. If you want it fixed, report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the CPU snapshot attached.

Comment: Should I be doing a CPU Profile Indexing ? The guide says the second meny option.

Comment: Do this: https://i.imgur.com/LEkOd1C.png .

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-235740?project=IDEA

Comment: Thank you! That's the right way to report such problems.